# Matplotlib fill_beween: remove color leak

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 4)
y = x ** 2
y2 = x ** 2.1
ax.fill_between(x, y, y2, alpha=0.25, color='red')
fig.save_fig('plot.pdf')
```

gives the following, when zooming in:

[image]

I don't want the boundaries (which are visible as lines) to appear.

This problem only occurs when I save the figure. Also, if I remove `color='red'`, the problem disappears as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `linewidth=0` removes the lines.

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 4)
y = x ** 2
y2 = x ** 2.1
ax.fill_between(x, y, y2, alpha=0.25, color='red', linewidth=0)
fig.save_fig('plot.pdf')
```